# Is there a WinForms way to do Application.Activate()?

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF-Application you can simply do this:

```
<Application x:Class="Activate.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Activate"
         Activated="App_OnActivated"
         Deactivated="App_OnDeactivated"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The intresting lines are:

```
         Activated="App_OnActivated"
         Deactivated="App_OnDeactivated"
```

Is there a way to get the same effect with a WinForms-Application?

---

## Edit

It seems I have not explained myself well, so here is an example project which I originally made for a collage.

Please try to note the difference between switching to a different application and just switching windows inside the application.

https://www.file-upload.net/download-13074329/Activate.zip.html

Comment: `Activate` and `Deactivate` events does also exist in winform. What effect are you looking to get ?

Comment: They are events, they have the exact same name.  If you want the method then consider BringToFront().  It is subject to restrictions, you can't push a window into the user's face when he's interacting with another app.

Comment: I have the feeling he wants to funnel all activated/deactivated event through a single one.

Comment: @Franck The events exists on Forms, but not on the application. Please see my edit.

Comment: @RamziKahil this is not a real event in WPF. An application cannot really have an activated event as it's not a visual object therefore cannot be activated by mouse or keyboard interaction. What WPF does is they trigger that event when any of the `Window.Activated` events are fired. In Winform you have to code it yourself and create a global event and make all your forms Activated and Deactivated event call that single event.

Comment: @RamziKahil Do you really care about doing something on the deactivated event ? or just knowing activated has happen coming from another app is enough ?

Comment: That is a good question. Me and a collage just had a discution about "what do we want to achieve anyway?", and at least one of them will be worked around. Anyway, I think I have enought info now. Thanks.

Comment: @RamziKahil if you don't care about the deactivated event then use the event to store a timestamp. Then when an activated is triggerer check if it's less than 1 second since last deactivate. If it is less than a second it mean your deactivate and activate are very close so you haven't switched to another application. If it's greater then the user has switched to something else in between

Answer (score 1):

On the form itself, you've got the following events available:

```
this.Activated += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Activated);
this.Deactivate += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Deactivate);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already tried that. Please see my edit.

Comment: The question about a window in the app versus the whole app: every Windows app has a "main window", which is what I assume you'd want to track. This is most obvious with an MDI app (you could track the parent window), but as I say - *every* app has at least 1 window.